# Find and associate a value in multiple excel spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, syntax

I looked over the internet for a similar problem but I can't find it, so it would be great if you can help. Or maybe I am not asking the correct questions to find the answer.

What I want to do is the following:

1- Firstly, **sheet1** has **"job code"** and **"job description"**. Job code has a number that relates to the job description. As the image below:
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xbXH.png)
(apparently, I am not allowed to post images here yet).

The spreadsheet is just a sample, as I have more than 60.000 entries, so I need to find the correct formula.

However, **sheet2** has a list of all of those codes and description, along with another number **"national codeX"**, as image: [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guEGs.png) that I need to relate to each of those entries in **sheet1**.

So, as a result, I wanted to know what formula to use to get in another column in **sheet1**, a match for the associated **national codeX** in **sheet2** and have that number returned. For example, in the result, I would see, after the date column, the corresponding number of the **national codeX** that matches the **job description code**.

Does that make sense?

I had a look at the Match formula, Vlookup and index, but I can't find the correct syntax. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. It needs to work on excel 2013.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Writing the following formula in F2 of Sheet1 should help. 

=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$1:$C$7,3,FALSE)

You may need to update $A$1:$C$7 if it doesn't fit the range of the data in the actual Sheet2 of yours. 

And to formula in F2 is needed to be copied below the cells as necessary.

Comment: Hi. I had to do an adjustment to look for the sheet2, as suggested:
=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,3,FALSE)
What does the 3 and the false mean in this context?
But it seems to have worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. I remembered it but it was later than the 5 minute margin a comment can be edited. 3 is the third column in the range given as the second paramete, that is the National CodeX in this case. False requires exact match and partial match is not allowed.

Comment: I had a look at a new one, XLOOKUP that also works. 
=XLOOKUP(Sheet1!C2,Sheet2!A2:A7,Sheet2!C2:C7)

Not sure why it was struggling before and returning #N/A. 
Anyway, I appreciate your help again.

Comment: XLOOKUP is a recent function and more advanced compared to VLOOKUP. There are times we all have similar experiences. Things not working before, starts working. And noone cares as long as they work. :)

Comment: Actually, it worked well, both of them in excel 2016, but it is not working on excel 2013. It returns #N/A. XLOOKUP is not available, but the VLOOKUP is not working either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Only thing that comes to my mind is data type mismatch. Sometimes, numbers are treated as text in Excel especially they come from an external source. This causes lookup functions fail to return a value.

Comment: I figured it out, "Another source N/A errors in VLOOKUP formulas is numbers being formatted as text". Now, it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that. My hunch has come out to be correct.

Comment: @MaxWill,, you can't get Job description based on National Code, since it's not common data in both sheets,, but the Job Code can be used,,, is this U r looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$7,3,FALSE)
```

or if you have excel 2019:

```
=XLOOKUP(Sheet1!C2,Sheet2!A2:A7,Sheet2!C2:C7)
```